# Listing buttons under each other in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

I know this sounds like a stupid question, but I spend like 3 hours trying to find this. 
There was some type of a list which you could enter buttons, labels, anything, inside it and it automatically put them under each other.

But I am not being able to find it again.. does any one know this?

Comment: Why are you spending half a day on this when you can just use css or alter the razor template?

Comment: I can, but with that was easier and Im trying to learn it, Im trying to learn more. I know how to do it with css. but I wanted to do it with this. wanted to learn this too

Comment: ListView is the way to handle a generic list with arbitrary content. Whether the alignment of items is inline or block is up to what you put in the template. Grid controls will give you tables, so the flow will always be vertical, but of course table layouts shouldn't be used for anything except real tables. Sure you know all this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alight=vertical seems to work for me